# Pipenv completely remove

Tags: python, pipenv

This makes no sense to me:

```bash
pipenv --venv
# No virtualenv has been created for this project(/Users/ak/Documents/myfolder) yet!
# Aborted!
```

```bash
pipenv --rm
# No virtualenv has been created for this project yet!
# Aborted!
```

```bash
pipenv shell
# Shell for /Users/ak/.local/share/virtualenvs/myfolder-7FUE3C-L already activated.
# No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

```bash
rm -r /Users/ak/.local/share/virtualenvs/myfolder-7FUE3C-L
# rm: /Users/ak/.local/share/virtualenvs/myfolder-7FUE3C-L: No such file or directory
```

```bash
deactivate
```

```bash
pipenv shell
# Shell for UNKNOWN_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT already activated.
# No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

What in the pipenv is going on, I just want to start my pipenv environment fresh but don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/84#issuecomment-275056943

Pressed CTRL-d to exit shell and was able to `pipenv shell`.